# Entity referenced property via postman for drupal 8

Tags: postman, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I've installed `address` module for a content type in my d8 site. The `address` module has a number of properties, of which some properties(postal code, pin code, state) are dependent on which country is selected. When adding content through UI, I first select a country and then based on it, below fields get displayed. Now, I want to create a node using postman for that content type. But in postman, I can't pass data for this field since it doesn't recognize which country is selected. Though it recognizes that required properties in `address` module is not null.

Before selecting country:
[image]

After selecting country:
[image]

Json content in postman:
[image]

The above four properties were required hence I had to pass some data to it. But when checked in my site, it shows the address as empty.

Comment: Looks like the address module makes at least 2 requests to the backend which you also need to create in Postman. Use the dev tools to see which requests are being made, then create them in Postman.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann how would I do that? I mean it will first sending the request to get country and then pass the other properties? or can I send both the request at one go ?

Comment: It's two requests: First setting the country. In the response you will probably get the data to be used in the second request.
Bit difficult for me to give advice here, I don't know the address module. But this is how it usually is handled.

Comment: okay. I'll try it and get back to you. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my error. For others who face the same issue(if ever) -

I didn't need to create a separate request to get country. I passed below json body in postman as a single request.

```
{
    "field_name_and_address_of_custom":[{"country_code":"IN", "given_name":"John", "family_name":"Doe", "organization":"ABC", "administrative_area":"state-name", "locality":"city-name", "postal_code":"123456", "pin_code":"1234567", "address_line1":"Address Line 1", "address_line2":"Address Line 2"}]
}
```

the field country was `country_code` and I needed to pass all other properties all together, like an array.